# How do I display static map image using MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

How do I display an area of a map as an image based on a coordinate without initializing `MKMapView`, similar to the one in the 'Meetup' app?

Initializing `MKMapView` in a table view cell will block the UI and it looks like the app hangs for a while.

Comment: you want to display image on map as pin ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom pin image in annotationView in iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839970/custom-pin-image-in-annotationview-in-ios-9)

Comment: problem solved by using MKMapSnapshotter.